# Do unique weapons exist for every weapon type in game?

Tags: fallout-4

Do unique weapons exist for every weapon type in game?  This means the pistols, rifles, miniguns that are all in-game, do unique versions of them exist, similar to how Fallout 3 and Fallout:NV had unique weapons?

If so, are these "unique" weapons customizable just like the base version?

Comment: An explanation to why this question was down-voted might be nice.
I don't think it's an obvious answer, unless you've got a guide/ist's in a guide.

Comment: @PhilD. Apparently some users here believe the questions I ask are all out of bad faith. They don't vote on the question because it's a good question/bad question for the site, they do it based on asker intent.

Comment: @r3tr0t3hPeNgU1NoFd00m, am curious how you were playing the game a day before release, though. I have seen accusations of piracy in relation to immediate downvoting, and this appears to support it.

Comment: @Timelord64 Nov 11 release was tied to digital content. Physical copies had been released in other countries prior to that date.

Comment: [Tweet from VP of Bethesda](https://twitter.com/DCDeacon/status/653907625445339136).  Even with a physical copy it won't work unless it is authenticated/completed in downloading everything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, true unique versions don't exist for every weapon but you can find legendary versions of pretty much every weapon in the game except for those special unique ones like the cryolator or alien blaster.

I already watched a video of someone modifying a unique weapon. Specifically, it was the unique Laser Rifle Righteous Authority, which is obtained from a quest, so yes you can modify the unique weapons to your heart's content. The unique weapons all get bonuses for their stats that they keep regardless of how you modify the weapon in the case of Righteous Authority. Critical shots always do double damage and crit meter fills 15% faster. The nice thing about this is you will be able to change the unique weapon to fit your play style, meaning the unique weapons will be far more useful then in many other games I have played where out of all the unique weapons I only use 1 or 2 because those are the only ones that fit my style of play.

Comment: How does answer the main question? It looks like it's just an answer to the secondary "If so, are these "unique" weapons customizable just like the base version?"

Comment: This question was asked back when the majority of the true unique weapons hadn't all been discovered yet DC so I didn't  answer that part. The current answer is no true unique don't exist for every weapon but you can find legendary versions of pretty much every weapon in the game except for those special unique ones like the cryolator or alien blaster.

Comment: Well that's all fine, but I just clicked on this question because I was interesting in seeing an answer. That's my downvote. If you have an updated answer, you should edit it in. Probably upvote once that happens.

Comment: Ugh. I hate that we call weapons like Righteous Authority 'unique.' It would have been great if the community could have picked something else, like 'named' to differentiate between truly unique weapons (like The Deliverer) and named legendaries.